# Injecting KLV data in video stream using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, klvdata

Does anyone here have any experience with streaming video on one stream, for example 0:0, and then taking a .bin file in klv format and putting it in 0:1, and then outputting that to a mpegts udp stream? I have it working, the only problem is that I have written a python program to update the klv data file while it is streaming, but it doesn't seem to be updated in the stream.

My command: ffmpeg -I "filepath.mpg" -f data -i "filepath.bin" -filter:v fps=60 -map 0:v:0 -map 1:d:0 -f mpegts udp://IP:PORT

Ive tried -I from a local file, I've also tried streaming the .bin file from an other stream after updating it, but then the fps drops to about 0.5.